# Struts2 with SLF4J and Logback produces double logs

Tags: struts2, slf4j

I have a very weird problem with Struts 2.1.8 and SLF4J with Logback. I think I have setup everything as it should be (logback-core, logback-classic, slf4j-api and removed commons-logging from Struts JARs), but the logs look like this:

16:23:59,985 INFO  [stdout] (ajp-localhost-127.0.0.1-8009-3) 2013-05-11 16:23:59,985 DEBUG [BasicTilesContainer.java:615] [ODk3Cc2-mn-X8eVfnemQn5WZ.undefined] - Render request recieved for definition 'DocumentList'

Clearly there are two timestamps, and one logging framework is logging through another somewhere, which causes this problem.

JBoss 7.1.1 is used.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

EDITED:

This is how Logback configuration looks like:

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d %5p [%F:%L] [%X{sessionId}] - %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

I had a problem with modules in JBoss 7, but now although they are solved and Logback is really loaded, but the log files still are a mess. They look like if they are logged through JUL:

```
20:23:46,128 INFO  [stdout] (connector_xxxx) 2013-05-11 20:23:46,127  DEBUG [ReConnector.java:83] [] - Next connection attempt in (ms) 20000
```

It looks like one logger is logging through the other.

Comment: I assume your logback config is a little special, do you perchance have two timestamps in your format string? Could you post the relevant section?

Comment: I just posted the update.

Comment: Update: it seems that this happens only for console/stdout logging, if I use file logger everything works fine.

Comment: output sent to the console is intercepted and logged. If the original output is generated by logging you get the appearance of double logging. Note that the time stamps are different!